# MySQL or Access: Add a : to the end of a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

This is probably the easiest thing to do, but I can't figure it out. I am trying to add a : to the end of each column in mysql or access. I have tried update, append and concat and I am not getting it right. So far, the closest I  got was using an append query. Although, I think using CONCAT is best, but not sure. This is my query:

```
UPDATE Vt_clients 
SET cl_postal_code = CONCAT([cl_postal_code]=+":")
WHERE cl_postal_code = '*'
```

Any information is greatly appreciated. Thanks, Beth

Comment: Are you looking for one SQL query that will work in either databases? Are you running a query in MS-Access to update a linked table in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

There is little syntax issue in your posted query. It should rather be

```
UPDATE Vt_clients 
SET cl_postal_code = CONCAT(`cl_postal_code`,':')
WHERE cl_postal_code = '*';
```

(OR) Use `+` operator for concatenation

```
UPDATE Vt_clients 
SET cl_postal_code = cl_postal_code + ':'
WHERE cl_postal_code = '*';
```

Comment: The second one works perfectly in access but not in mysql.

Comment: @bethabernathy, that's why there is two version provided in answer. but it should work in MySQL too